# $x\int_0^a xdx$ same as $\int_0^a x^2dx$?

Tags: integration

let $g(x) = xf(x)$ 
where $f(x) = \int_0^a x  dx$

Is this equivalent to $g(x)=\int_0^a x^2dx$?

I am confused to which solution it leads to :

$x[\frac 1 2 x^2]_0^a = x\frac 1 2 a^2$ or $\frac 1 3 a^3$

Many thanks in advance

Comment: No, $\int_0^a x^2 \; dx$ is constant (since $a$ appears to be fixed), while $x\int_0^a x\; dx$ is not constant (for $a\not=0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $f(x)$ as you defined it isn't actually a function of $x$.  $x$ is the variable of integration.  If you wanted to amend this you can change the variable of integration by defining

$$
f(x) \;\; =\;\; \int_0^x ydy.
$$

From this we would find that $xf(x) \neq g(x) = \int_0^x y^2dy$ since we would have

$$
xf(x) \;\; =\;\; x \int_0^x ydy \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{2} x^3 \;\; \neq \;\; \frac{1}{3}x^3 \;\; =\;\; \int_0^x y^2dy.
$$